# read input from user and print it back on console in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

Im trying to make simple program which will read input from user and print it back on console here is part of mine program

```
LEAF(main)

#Print to user enter integer
    li    a0,1                # first argument fd 1
    la    a1,prompt           # second argument memory location of hello string
    li    a2,20               # lenght of string to print
    li    v0,__NR_write       # syscall write,they are defined in unistd.h
    syscall

#Raad the integer and save it in s0
    li    a0,0                # first argument for stdin is 0
    li    a1,unknown          # second argument is unknown
    li    a2,unknown          # third arg is also unknown
    li    v0,__NR_read
    syscall
    move s0, v0
```

So mine program waits for input from user and after entering 1 or 9 the value of v0 and and S0 (inspected with gdb) are 0x2 not 0x1 and 0x9 respectively.

Edit:
so i just found this

```
sys_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
```

so second argument is __user *buf so its pointer to a *buf so is this where I should store it ?
and third argument is size_t count but count for what ? Count of number of byts ?

Comment: Assuming you're running this on some sort of MIPS Linux distro (and not in a simulator like SPIM/MARS), the read system call needs three arguments: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L562

Comment: Yes thats correct Im running this on my mips router not is simulator, thats great thank you Michael, so first argument is file descriptor, how can I find which number is it

Comment: Well, how did you know you needed `fd 1` for output? Presumably it's written in the same place what you need for input. Hint: `stdin` is `fd 0`.

Comment: I found it in some example that fd 1 is output which did not mentioned input. Tnx for hint Jester so my first argument in a0, is 0

Comment: Your write `syscall` is correct. It corresponds to `man 2 write` (i.e. `write(1,prompt,20)`). Likewise for read. This is from userspace [what you want as you're writing an application program]. The `sys_read` definition is how the _kernel_ defines the read syscall internally. Similar, but, just follow the man page instead. Note that after doing the read, the buffer will have an _ascii_ string (i.e. _not_ a binary number). So, you'll have to call `atoi` or `strtol` [or write your own], just as you would in a `c` program

Comment: Tnx Craig i tried to place memory address to second argument but it give me seg fault, could you help me about second argument ?

Comment: I just read man 2 write and they did not mentioned const void *buf anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it here is an answer

```
#Read the integer and save it in s0
    nop
    nop
    li    a0,0      # firs argument, for stdin is 0 ISTR, see "man 2 read"
    la    a1,(var1) # second argument load adress of var1 into a1
    li    a2,12     # third argument is count of byts 
    li    v0,__NR_read
    syscall
.data

var1:      .space     256
```